# Drag drop support in Office js Word Add-in

Tags: angularjs, office365

I wish to drag drop an item from a list from my Add-in .Is it supported by Office.js?

Comment: It is posible with Angular js dont know about Office.js, As both are JavaScript, you can make drag/drop functionality using javaScript code.

Comment: What kind of items? What kind of list? What do you need to do with these items?

Comment: The list will have string text items.I wish to create content control via drag drop on the document . The Tag of the content control is the text of the list item.

Comment: @EricLegault Needed some pointers on this.

Comment: This would only be possible with a COM Add-in that can trap mouse events through the Win32 API